# Bypass websocket traffic for squid

Tags: websocket, squid

Squid doesnt support WebSocket traffic `(wss://)`. Im using squid as a bridged interceptor acting as a forward proxy. I have tried the `always_direct` and `ssl_bump splice` directive such as the examples below, but none seems to work. Has anyone been successful with getting websocket traffic to work on squid (read: bypassed) yet keeping `ssl bump` enabled for everything else?

```
acl websocket url_regex ^wss://.*$
always_direct allow websocket
```

```
acl websocket url_regex ^wss://.*$
ssl_bump splice websocket
```